# Уникальный генератор паролей без повторяющихся символов?

Tags: php, html

Хочу поделиться с вами своим кодом и его проблемами:

```
<?php
$alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

$opt1 = "23456789";
$opt2 = strtoupper($alpha);
$opt2 = str_replace('O', '', $opt2);
$opt3 = str_replace('l', '', $alpha);
$chars = "";

if (isset($_POST['length'])){
    // if you want a form like above
    if (isset($_POST['opt1']) && $_POST['opt1'] == 'on')
        $chars .= $opt1;
    if (isset($_POST['opt2']) && $_POST['opt2'] == 'on')
        $chars .= $opt2;
    if (isset($_POST['opt3']) && $_POST['opt3'] == 'on')
        $chars .= $opt3;
    $length = $_POST['length'];
}

$len = strlen($chars);
$pw = '';

for ($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
        $pw .= substr($chars, rand(0, $len-1), 1);

// the finished password
$pw = str_shuffle($pw);

?>

<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    <h3>Select Characters</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="opt1"> Numbers without 0 and 1
    <input type="checkbox" name="opt2"> Big letters without O and o
    <input type="checkbox" checked="on" name="opt3"> Small letters without "l"
    <h3 style="margin: 20px 0;">Password Length</h3>
    <input type="text" name="length" size="2" maxlength="2">
    <input type="submit" value="Generate">
    <div style="padding: 20px 0;">
        <div>Your Password:</div>
        <div style="width:200px; height:15px; border:1px black solid; font-size: 14px; font-family: monospace; padding:3px; color:#000; background-color: #D2E0E6; margin: 0;"><?php echo $pw ?></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

- Символы в пароле не должны повторяться.
- Создаваемые пароли должны быть уникальными.
- Если пользователь выбрал 3 множества, то пароль должен содержать символы из всех множеств, хотя бы по 1 из каждого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо объединения всех строк с доступными символами в одну строку, оставьте их раздельно.

Положим, длина пароля = 10, и задано использовать все три множества. Значит, максимальное количество символов из первого множества (цифры) = 10 − (3 − 1) = 8. Вычисляем число символов из первого множества как `rand(1, 8)`. Допустим, получили 5. Значит, для второго множества символов остаётся максимум 10 − 5 − (2 − 1) = 4. Вычисляем как `rand(1, 4)`. Для третьего множества остаются все остальные символы.

Затем последовательно конкатенируем заданное количество символов из каждого множества и вызываем `str_shuffle`.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем всё так усложнять. Bash однострочник вида:

```
date +%s%3N | md5 | base64 | md5 | base64 | cut -c1-8
```

Вполне сойдет для генерации паролей для простого сайта. Вместо 8 подставьте нужную длину пароля и все.

**Предупреждение!** Не применяйте этот генератор если безопасность критична. Единственное его достоинства в простоте реализации.

Comment: shell_exec - плохая идея в данном случае (судя по подготовке автора вопроса)

Comment: Да, не подумал как-то, уберу от греха подальше, но все равно однострочник мне нравится, так что я оставлю его здесь.

Comment: О боги! Что это?! Зачем два раза вызывать хэш-функцию? Зачем два раза переводить в base64? Это жестокое надругательство над безопасностью, вы искусственно ограничиваете множество исходных сообщений. Я уж не говорю о том, что ответ никак не соотносится с вопросом.

Comment: @Athari Угу осталось только через diehard и NIST этот быстрогенератор прогнать. Хотя вы конечно правы, единственное его достойинство в том что он состоит из одной строки. Не стоит его применять если безопасность  критична.

Answer (score 0):

Аналог предыдущего ответа на PHP

```
base64_encode(md5(base64_encode(md5(time()))));
```

UPD
Извращение конечно, но работает как надо

```
join('',array_unique(str_split(base64_encode(md5(microtime(1).uniqid())))));
```