# Генератор уникальных ID

Tags: php, generate, password

Нужен код генератора уникальных ID. Поискал в интернете. Нашел функцию 
 `uniqid()` но уникальность не гарантируется. Нашел в SO [эту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413367/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) статью. 
Но так как я новичок то не понял как можно его изменить (т.к. он работает некорректно). Скажите как его поменять? и на ваш взгляд он будет выдавать уникальные ID?

Comment: [UUID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID) не подойдут?

Comment: я бы сказал то что надо ))

Comment: @DmitriySimushev если занудствовать, UUID, даже версии 4, тоже не гарантирует уникальность)

Comment: @andreymal, об этом я и написал в своем ответе. На практике, вероятность того, что для UUIDv4 будут сгененрированы два одинаковых ID стремится к нулю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует специальный стандарт генерации псевдо-случайных идентификаторов с высокой степенью уникальности: [UUID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID). Хотя теоретически идентификаторы сгенерированные по этому стандарту могут повторяться, на практике вы смело может рассматривать их как уникальные.

В PHP есть уже готовая библиотека, реализующая этот стандарт: https://github.com/ramsey/uuid. Вот как ее можно использовать:

```
$uuid = \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4();
echo $uuid; // 550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000
```

Answer (score 3):

В качестве альтернативы UUID можно использовать [ksuid](https://segment.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-the-uuid/), который, как и UUIDv4, использует случайные биты, но дополнительно содержит метку времени, позволяя тем самым сортировать идентификаторы по дате, и при этом избавлен от исторически сложившихся сложностей с версиями и вариантами UUID, а также от привязки к железу (MAC-адресу и прочему).

[image]

Одна из реализаций на PHP: https://github.com/tuupola/ksuid

```php
use Tuupola\Ksuid;

$ksuid = new Ksuid;

/* Base62 представление */
print $ksuid; /* 0o5Fs0EELR0fUjHjbCnEtdUwQe3 */

/* HEX представление */
print bin2hex($ksuid->bytes()); /* 05a95e21d7b6fe8cd7cff211704d8e7b9421210b */

/* Чтение отдельных частей ksuid */
print $ksuid->timestamp(); /* 94985761 */
print $ksuid->unixtime(); /* 1494985761 */
print bin2hex($ksuid->payload()); /* d7b6fe8cd7cff211704d8e7b9421210b */

/* Варианты парсинга существующих ksuid */
use Tuupola\KsuidFactory;
$ksuid = KsuidFactory::fromString('0o5Fs0EELR0fUjHjbCnEtdUwQe3');
$ksuid = KsuidFactory::fromBytes(hex2bin('05a95e21d7b6fe8cd7cff211704d8e7b9421210b'));
$ksuid = new Ksuid(94985761, hex2bin('d7b6fe8cd7cff211704d8e7b9421210b'));
```