# Как сгенерировать UUID с помощью PHP?

Tags: php, uuid

Нужна строка вот такого вида, которая вроде как состоит из случайных чисел:

```
f23e4567-e89b-42d3-a456-426655440000
```

Что это за строка и как получить её средствами PHP?

Comment: Таки да, в таком виде вопрос намного лучше)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Генератор уникальных ID](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668084/Генератор-уникальных-id)

Answer (score 4):

Перед нами [UUID v4](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID#%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_4_(%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)), который имеет формат вида:

```
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Цифра четыре в примере в вопросе находится на этом же месте. Подробное определение формата есть в [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122). В зависимости от требовательности софта, для которого вы генерируете этот UUID, может быть можно будет использовать полностью случайную строку, но если нужно чтобы UUID был по формату (например, когда софт проверяет что за UUID вы ему подсовываете), стоит использовать готовую и протестированную библиотеку для получения UUID именно нужной версии.

Например, [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid), которая устанавливается обычно, через Composer. Пример использования:

```
$uuid4 = \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4();
echo $uuid4;
```

Точно таким же образом можно получить UUID других версий.

Ещё одна причина использовать готовые библиотеки: они страхуют вас от ошибок при получении случайных строк. Например, если наивно использовать `mt_rand()` для получения случайных чисел, то можно попасть в неприятную ситуацию когда вашу строку смогут угадать посторонние, что может быть возможно потому что `mt_rand()` [не генерирует криптографически безопасные значения](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mt-rand.php).